# Find the link between these everyday words?

Tags: english, wordplay

You have to simply step forward and find the common link between these words:

**age, date, drill, go, hole**

The correct link works in the exact same way for each of the words.

Comment: "simply step forward" - Caesar shift maybe?

Comment: @randal'thor: Nope. Much simpler.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can ...

> ... append each of these words to the word "man" to make new English words:
>
>  man**age**, man**date**, man**drill**, man**go**, man**hole**

Comment: I like how "hole" retains its basic meaning but the others are *completely* different

Comment: @EngineerToast: I had aimed to choose such words where the meaning changes to a great extent with the 'man' prefix. Even with manhole, it became too specific, so I let it stay in my series of words.

Comment: @CodeNewbie: And drill and hole make a good red herring, as do age and date.

Answer (score 4):

Could it be:

> things you lie/use as excuses?

I would think that

> people, especially children, would lie about all of the above to get out of something.
>  i.e "I'm eighteen," "Sorry dude, I got a date," "Of course I finished my drills, Coach!", "Yeah, I went to the study session," and finally, "I didn't make that hole in the yard looking for dinosaurs! It was aliens!!"

Comment: +1, This answer is brilliant! I love your creative logic.

Answer (score 4):

The common link **between** the words "age**,** date**,** drill**,** go**,** hole"
is, quite clearly,

> ", "

Answer (score 3):

I am Not sure, but it's may be Archaeology

**Age & Date** : Archaeology is the study of the ancient and recent human past through material remains.

**Drill & Hole** : Drill & Hole for analysis of the material

**Go** : Visit Different Places.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE! I don't think this is the answer though, since the OP says "The correct link works in the exact same way for each of the words."

Answer (score 2):

Another association:

This might be reference to your life (like the [Riddle of the Sphinx](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphinx#The_Riddle_of_the_Sphinx)):

**Age** you are born and from now on it is increasing continuously, you are getting older, you are aging

**Date** you have your first love, you date

**Drill** you are conscripted (in some countries) or go to work, you have some duties you have to follow

**Go** you leave your parents, or alternatively you get retired

**Hole** you die and are put in a hole in soil, on cemetery, you get buried

What might be wrong and does not match is that the last word is not a verb. However, this is not a verb intentionally, because this is the moment when you are not able to perform any action (see also the 3rd meaning on [the Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hole#Verb)).