# The lengthy and boring adventures of

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, story, connect-wall

[image: Pic not related to the puzzle]

I happened to write a book once. It was told by the main character - an educated adventurous gentleman with a long yet dignified name. Yet, when I sent the manuscript to the publisher, they told me that not only was it extremely boring, I also had to change the name of the hero.

I was so shocked, that I ripped and threw away my book, and forgot everything about it.

Today I found several pieces of it and it doesn't look as bad as I remember (perhaps I got a little nostalgic, though). I could even try to rewrite it from the scratch. The only problem, though, I can't remember the name of the main character that I liked so much. Also, some of the pieces I found don't make a lot of sense (supplying tar for parties, for instance). That's why I need SE help once again!

excerpt 1 (preface)

> Young people nowadays tend to r, might I say, "cool" things. The w world is open to them after they "leave d in various subjects, yet remaining infantile. I had already mastered clan my years of college, but modern youth prefers to foolishly try drums, guitar, c.

excerpt 2 (college hobby)

> After a while I mand to mase bread baking. I became a permanent supplier of tar, sometimes, canapes for student parties. I've even experimented with hallucinogenic products: my hashish cakes were exceptionally good, and M were still acceptable. By the time I got my graduation ndless offers of a job from restaurants were going my way; but I had already chosen to be an adventurer.

excerpt 3 (lucky note)

> While I was hastily making a fire to protect myself from the danger, I saw the last oming for me. He was alone - a minute ago his ban all of my friends, one by one, so he was the only one remaining hungry. In that exact moment the pebble fell from my clumsy hand and cluttered on the temple's we ceramic floor tiles, making a weirdly pure sound. What surprised me, the made the ogre stop in its place, as if he was stunned! It was similar to that time when my music skills made a dramant, back in the Cave of Death...

excerpt 4 (sickness)

> Many ed doctors gave up, trying to find the reason for my disease. I can say, ness is the only one that treats me now; those weird psychis are getting stronger with each day. An ancient doctor once claimed that den jars, accumulate the sickness inside for our whole lives, and we get sick only if the a "bursts through" to vital organs.

Now, as always, I state the criteria (bonus questions are not necessary to get the tick):

**1. Find and correct all the mistakes.** 
 **2. What's the hero's name?** 
 **3. Can I use it and why?**

**Hint 1** (graph from the book draft):

> [image: M's emotionally unstable, as every adventurer should be!]

.

> CORRECTION: ORANGE graph should end at 3, not 4! (sorry)

**Hint 1 explained nicely**

> Each of the 4 paragraphs makes for 5 hidden words. Having taken the amount of letters in every word, and then stacking them in order: each paragraph produces a 5-point graph. The remaining graph can be considered a red herring for now (though it too has a meaning)

**Hint 2**

> I used two words ending with "i" in one of the excerpts; both are shortened versions of full words.

*I think hints would be too straight-forward. I'm going to post screenshots of Gareth's existing answer (see me as the ouija board spirit).*

Screenshot 1:

> [image: missing link?]

Comment: It's funny that I could make some real mistakes during creation of these puzzle. Please, report on those here in the comments if you're quite sure. Don't blatantly edit the thing :)

Comment: Your list of criteria goes 1,2,2,4. The 2 should probably be a 3.

Comment: (Apparently something about this puzzle makes 3s turn into 2s :-).)

Comment: I might know part of your character's name.

Comment: (Actually, perhaps the name I think I have identified is merely a pointer to your character's name. Though in that case I'm not sure yet how I would pick an alternative. Of course I may be completely misunderstanding how this works, though I don't _think_ so.)

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan I believe you're on the right track (though I have no reason to believe in it, having _not_ seen any of your solution). But your reputation suggests you're quite an expert at puzzles of sorts.

Comment: I'm not so sure this one is an error, but it _looks_ more like an error than part of the puzzle: should "job" be "jobs" in excerpt 2?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87346/discussion-between-thomas-blue-and-gareth-mccaughan).

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan I think the graph may be of use for you.

Comment: Noted! Though at first glance the only obviously-useful thing in the graph is not actually part of the graph. The second hint looks useful, too. I may be rather occupied with other things today.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure about the third point on the thin purple-blue line? <--- EDITED to add: Oops, that's total nonsense: I miscounted something. That line is fine. Sorry.

Comment: Sad that it looks as if rot13(tbat bqbe) has to be wrong. Unless maybe some of those points can denote rot13(zhygvcyr jbeqf bs gur fnzr yratgu va gur fnzr fybg).

Comment: But in that case it looks to me as if the third point on the thick blue line would have to be wrong. Of course when I say "X would have to be wrong" what I really mean is "probably I am getting something wrong, but ..." :-).

Comment: @GarethMacCaughan You wouldn't imagine how close is rot13(tbat bqbe) to the right thing.

Comment: I guess I could replace those two four-letter words with a single 6-letter (fictional) proper noun. The 3-letter word in that paragraph would still have to be wrong but replacing it with an 8 might be more manageable than replacing it with a 4 as it currently seems like I have to do.

Comment: You're talking about the red graph? If so, I don't see what would be a problem with a 3-letter word and why would you replace it.

Comment: Actually, I think that (for reasons that I already cannot reconstruct) I was talking about the black graph. D'oh.

Comment: Nice picture! $(+1) \ \color{orange}{\bigstar}$ :D

Comment: @user477343 Thanks! That's a random picture of a generic explorer I found on the Internet. Note that neither the picture nor the watermark have nothing to do with the puzzle :)

Comment: Oh... well, I might try this tomorrow then if nobody else has the answer... yet ;)

Comment: @ThomasBlue Just to be explicit: is the double negative deliberate, or did you mean to say that neither the picture nor its watermark has anything to do with the puzzle?

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan My bad, that was a grammar mistake. Neither of them has anything to do with the puzzle.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As the puzzle says,

> the manuscript has been torn, and each of these excerpts is missing some bits. In each case the missing bits form words or names. And, as indicated in a hint, the lengths (in letters) of the missing bits are shown by four of the five graphs. We shall see in due course what the fifth graph is for.

Excerpt 1:

> Young people nowadays tend to **do rad o**r, might I say, "cool" things. The w**hole** world is open to them after they "leave **uni" verse**d in various subjects, yet remaining infantile. I had already mastered cla**vi i**n my years of college, but modern youth prefers to foolishly try drums, guitar, **bass et**c. [Lengths: 6,4,8,3,6.]

Excerpt 2:

> After a while I man**age**d to mas**ter ry**e bread baking. I became a permanent supplier of ta**pas o**r, sometimes, canapes for student parties. I've even experimented with hallucinogenic products: my hashish cakes were exceptionally good, and M**J ones** were still acceptable. By the time I got my graduation **cap e**ndless offers of a job from restaurants were going my way; but I had already chosen to be an adventurer. [Lengths: 3,5,4,5,4.]

Excerpt 3:

> While I was hastily making a fire to protect myself from the danger, I saw the last o**grec o**ming for me. He was alone - a minute ago his ban**d ate** all of my friends, one by one, so he was the only one remaining hungry. In that exact moment the pebble fell from my clumsy hand and cluttered on the temple's w**hit**e ceramic floor tiles, making a weirdly pure sound. What surprised me, the **flint's tone** made the ogre stop in its place, as if he was stunned! It was similar to that time when my music skills made a dra**gon dor**mant, back in the Cave of Death... [Lengths: 5,4,3,10,6.]

Excerpt 4:

> Many **train**ed doctors gave up, trying to find the reason for my disease. I can say, **Dr Ill**ness is the only one that treats me now; those weird psychi**c ache**s are getting stronger with each day. An ancient doctor once claimed that **we, as Ley**den jars, accumulate the sickness inside for our whole lives, and we get sick only if the a**cid** "bursts through" to vital organs. [Lengths: 5,5,5,7,3.]

Summarizing:

> `DORADO HOLE  UNIVERSE VII        BASSET
> AGE    TERRY PASO     JONES      CAPE
> GRECO  DATE  HIT      FLINTSTONE GONDOR
> TRAIN  DRILL CACHE    WEASLEY    CID
> 3      4     4        2          4`

and now we have

> five groups of four words (where OP has indicated that each group has one word from each excerpt) each lead to a word whose length is given by one number in the last set. So we have BASSET, CAPE, GONDOR, TRAIN -> HORN; HOLE, AGE, DATE, DRILL -> MAN (kudos yet again to MOehm for noticing that one); UNIVERSE, TERRY, HIT, CACHE -> MISS; DORADO, PASO, GRECO, CID -> EL; VII, JONES, FLINTSTONE, WEASLEY -> FRED. (FRED also goes with BASSET, but OP's hint suggests it doesn't here. FRED/MISS TERRY/JONES could have been put the other way around, but OP has indicated that this way was intended.) We can put our final set of five words together to make MANFRED MISSELHORN, which could be the character's name (we know it starts with M). That happens to be the name of a retired Olympic rower; it's not clear to me whether that's enough reason to change it.

So, to address the three things we are challenged to do:

1. *Find and correct all the mistakes.* Done; see above.
2. *What's the hero's name?*

> Probably MANFRED MISSELHORN.

3. *Can I use it and why?*

> You can use it if, and only if, the coincidence with that rower's name isn't a problem. Using existing names isn't always bad (I'm sure there were lots of Harry Potters before J K Rowling came along) but a *rather unusual* name shared with a *somewhat eminent* person is probably a bit too much. You should change it.

Credit where due: *much* of the above was contributed by MOehm in comments. Specifically:

> excerpt 1's DO/RAD/O and UNI/VERSE; excerpt 3's FLINT/STONE; excerpt 4's DRILL, WEASLEY (though I will take what little credit is due for thinking of "Leyden jars"), and ACID; noticing the [connect-wall] tag; spotting MAN as a connection between several of the words, which may also be how he thought of DRILL.

So if you like anything in this answer, go and upvote something of his.

Also, the first gap in the last excerpt was provided by OP, neither I nor MOehm having been able to figure it out.

Comment: Though I was about to start giving hints, your post gave me lots of faith in the local folks. I'll probably refrain from giving hints for some time (though there are places were you hit real close and my initial reflex was to correct you)

Comment: @ThomasBlue Yes, wait! Nothing is worse than a spoilt puzzle out of OA impatience. I'd say, give it at least until after Xmas!

Comment: rot13("Oxmz" yustf nq "oxmduzqf uz".)

Comment: That actually seems to be rot12. Anyway, the trouble with that is that RINETI doesn't make any sense.

Comment: name of char = perhaps rot13(z) as in hint 1?

Comment: Miss El Paso? Think big -- one of the global contests will give you the 8-letter answer in the first section.

Comment: Some RPGs have a monster called [ogre magi](https://dota2.gamepedia.com/Ogre_Magi), which would make a nice word ending in C. The word in 4.2 could be "drill" for "Dr Illness". Too bad the overall solution for 2 doesn't have [only 3 letters](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/17218/find-the-link-between-these-everyday-words).

Comment: Cor, that's an impressive bit of (_clearly correct_) jumping to conclusions @MOehm!

Comment: Actually, "clearly correct" is pushing it. I was misremembering what was where when I wrote that. (But maybe some things are not where I think they are, of course.)

Comment: "Magi" is plural, surely.

Comment: It usually is, but it seems to be used in singular in the RPG universe. Maybe I'm using wishful thinking to make "magic" fit. As far as I know, the Magi were not known for eating people ...

Comment: Bleh, I see it isn't in DOTA2 (where it's the title of a specific creature). In any other context, though, _magi_ is the plural of _magus_. Still, anything's possible...

Comment: I hadn't thought about rearranging the words, but there is a "Connect Wall" tag I failed to see earlier! That opens up many opportunities. Word 4.4 could be (Ron) Weasley, a character from Harry Potter. Word 1.3 is (Miss) Universe. Word 1.4 could be ?IN instead of psi, perhaps gin if clang were something one could master. (Plus a Gordon theme -- Terry? Jones?)

Comment: Yow! I didn't see it either. Was it always there?

Comment: ... Answer: it's been there since revision 8 on 2018-12-28. Duh.

Comment: It's not MAGI, I'm glad to say -- but, alas, it is GIN :-).

Comment: Like the connect-wall tag, El Greco was there all along. D'oh! (Oh, and the kids today tend to DO RAD Or cool things.)

Comment: Brilliant! (And I would never, never have found that.)

Comment: To give your good guess of FRED some more currency: It was the flint's tone that made the ogre stop. Now we're missing only a 3-letter word and a 5-letter word that must fit Miss and Horn. I'm pretty sure your ingenious suggestion of the final name is correct.

Comment: Flint's tone -- OMG. Well done. You should be getting all the points for this one.

Comment: Good news for you: it isn't GIN either. The last word is (EL) CID. That re-opens "clan". The OP has said that in one excerpt, he used two words ending in I and that these words are shortenings of longer words. We have used "uni", so that leaves one. I guess that the PSI construction (but perhaps not the word itself) is correct. (If you look at the history, you'll find that all major discoveries here are yours. I only worked backwards from your findings, and not always with success. And were're not in it for the rep, are we?)

Comment: since the name is correct I will give a tick. The problem with further guessing is that 3 skipped letters in the first excerpt is not exactly a word. I will also say that every group does have one word in every excerpt (though the order is random).

Comment: CID is nice. I can't match PSI with either MISS or HORN (and Qat can't find anything --I that forms a word when combined with either, for what it's worth) but I too suspect that that sort of construction is correct for the CLAN slot.

Comment: If each word in a group comes from a different excerpt, Fred comes from #1 (3 letters) and Horn from #4 (5 letters). And (Fred / Miss) go to (Terry / Jones), but it can go either way. Perhaps Fred [has a number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fred_VII) and clavi is short for clavier or clavichord? That would explain the disdain for the modern instruments, but I'm not super convinced.

Comment: Could be. I don't like VII much either, but it's by no means impossible (and constructing the puzzle involves quite a lot of constraints, so we should expect some slightly forced constructions).

Comment: I hadn't noticed that OP had indicated that all groups are one-per-excerpt. I think Fred Terry / Miss Jones is better than the other pairing. There are a number of 5-letter things that can go with "ed" and "horn" but I haven't found any that really work for me...

Comment: Blasted? Perhaps @ThomasBlue could put us out of our misery, now that the tick has been awarded. That was a good puzzle. I like the basic idea, but it was quite tough.

Comment: @MOehm My apology, sometimes an idea for the puzzle just gets stuck in the head and I can't realize it properly, lacking the language skills. Anyway, gur IVV nffhzcgvba vf pbeerpg, V nyfb jnf nvzvat sbe Zvff Greel (sebz fbzr byq zbivr, V guvax) naq Serq Wbarf sebz Fpbbol-qbb frevrf (fbzrubj V raqrq hc tngurevat bayl gur vzntvanel Serqf). Rirel bgure qrgnvy vf pbzcyrgryl ba gur fcbg. Gur jbeq V jnf nvzvat sbe va gur ynfg rkprecg jnf "genvarq".

Comment: Good puzzle, and no apologies needed.

Comment: Thanks for clearing up the last bits. No need to apologise or be hard on yourself. It was tough, but fun.